# .htaccess redirect href (from facebook or google) to main page

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, redirect, google-search

I'm trying to make a .htaccess file to help me with:
-if someone access my website secondary pages (adau.ga/xxx.php) or images(adau.ga/images/xxx.jpg) from anoather website (facebook, google, etc.) to redirect them to main page www.adau.ga/index.php.

Can this be done?
I made this this code:

```
rewriteengine on                
#RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.adau.ga/#portfolio
```

And it seems that if it works for the links on facebook, but for google they don't work.

Help, please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://adau.ga/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://adau.ga$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.adau.ga/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.adau.ga$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(txt|html|htm|php|swf)$ http://adau.ga [R,NC]
```